# laravel how to remove authentication provide by laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

How to uninstall or remove authentication provide by laravel?
I need to replacing the laravel authentication with a custom authentication.

Comment: Just override everything in app/Http/Controllers/Auth .. If you want te create you own, comment Auth facade and AuthServiceProvider from your config/app.php

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to use Laravel out-of-the-box authentication, but it's pretty easy to [customize it](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) the way you want to.